# React native cannot import some of the SVG

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg

I have some SVG from my client, and these SVG have to import to the react native app.
I found out that all these SVG from client cannot import , but I can import SVG which is from internet.

Here is the one of test SVG from client: https://svgur.com/s/sLK.

---

**I had tried to use all the import method:**
1.Using SVGUri

- error message:"tried to register two views with the same name rnsvgrect"

Using import SVG from ../../assets/mysvg.svg'

- error message: "TypeError: _reactNative.Linking.removeEventListener is not a function. (In '_reactNative.Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleDeepURL)', '_reactNative.Linking.removeEventListener' is undefined)
  "

I have notice that the not working SVG contain Graphic.Depths element, I am not sure is it cause the issue.

```
<Graphic.Depths>
    <DepthInfo DepthName="Depth 1" DisplaySize="1840" ActiveLayerInDepth="Layer 1" />
  </Graphic.Depths>
  <Graphic.Datapoints>...</Graphic.Datapoints>
```

---

metro.config.js

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts },
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer"),
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"],
    },
  };
})();

/**
 * Metro configuration for React Native
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
};
```

---

Package version
"react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0"
react-native-svg : not include in package, it does not work even I include this package in package.json

I have search for reason of importing svg failure, but it seems not my case because my case is not all SVG cannot import, only certain kind of SVG does not work.